# Can I monitor the progress of an S3 download using the AWS SDK?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm using the AWS SDK package from Nuget to download files from S3. This involves creating a GetObject request. Amazon has [an example of how to do this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html) in their documentation, although I'm actually using the async version of the method.

My code to download a file looks something like this:

```
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretAccessKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
{
    var request = new GetObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = "my-bucket",
        Key = "file.exe"
    };

    using (var response = await client.GetObjectAsync(request))
    {
        response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(@"C:\Downloads\file.exe");
    }
}
```

This works; it downloads the file successfully. However, it seems like a little bit of a black box, in that I never really know how long it's going to take to download the file. What I'm hoping to do is get some sort of Progress event so that I can display a nice WPF ProgressBar and watch the download progress. This means I would need to know the size of the file and the number of bytes downloaded, and I'm not sure if there's a way to do that with the AWS SDK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do:

```
using (var response = client.GetObject(request))
{
  response.WriteObjectProgressEvent += Response_WriteObjectProgressEvent;
  response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(@"C:\Downloads\file.exe");
}

private static void Response_WriteObjectProgressEvent(object sender, WriteObjectProgressArgs e)
{
  Debug.WriteLine($"Tansfered: {e.TransferredBytes}/{e.TotalBytes} - Progress: {e.PercentDone}%");
}
```

Comment: How can you do this in nodejs/javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Can you hook in to the [WriteObjectProgressEvent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/E_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtilityDownloadRequest_WriteObjectProgressEvent.htm) object? If you subscribe to events from this object your function will be called multiple times during the download. It will receive the number of bytes that are downloaded/remaining so you can build a progress indicator.